# Why is my 'export' option missing?

Tags: wp-admin, export

My tools>export option has vanished - even when reverting to the default TwentySeventeen theme.

Direct access to /wp-admin/export.php delivers 'Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.'
I'm wondering 'why', and what the fix is.

UPDATE...

I restored the missing option by adding this to functions:

`$admin_role = get_role( 'administrator' );
$admin_role->add_cap( 'export', true );`

And now, even when that code is commented-out, 'export' is available.

I don't pretend to understand why.

Comment: Are you sure that you have logged as a Admin? Seems like some others also has your problem. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-46-tools-export-missing/

Comment: @Ranuka... Thanks. Yep, definitely logged-in as admin. Also created another admin and tried that - no different. Seemed to happen while making various changes (but same issue with default theme suggests that's not the cause), including switch to SSL (though can't imagine why that'd be an issue). I'd seen those other posts with similar problems before posting here,Very strange.

Comment: Did you disable all plugins? Because some plugin may hide that option.

Comment: @Ranuka... Thanks. I haven't, because I didn't add any new plugins or update any current. Now having tried that, even with default theme 'export' is still absent. And, on reverting to my custom theme, with no active plugins I've no access to sub-menus.

Comment: Quick update to previous comment... should read 'I've no mouseover access to sub-menus - have to click main item to show sub-menu'.

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the same problem. I wanted to export content from my free WordPress site to my new self-hosted WordPress site. But I couldn't see the export option in my setting. All you have to do is get support from wordpress itself. You can get detailed information here https://wordpress.com/support/export/

To directly export, click on this link https://wordpress.com/export

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thankyou for your help.